# Discord.py getting members in voice channels on all servers

Tags: discord.py

I want to print out the IDs of all Discord users that is connected to voice channels the Discord bot is connected to. The bot has administrator rights on all Discords and have access to all channels. I have tried to use this piece of code to do it, but I simply don't get it to work. The channel.members only returns an empty list.
(I have of course checked that there actually were people connected to voice channels)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
global client

prefix = "-"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, case_insensitive=True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.voice_channels:
            for member in channel.members:
                print(member.id)

client.run("XXXXXX")
```

Comment: do you have intents.members enabled?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Yes, but does the bot require verification to be able to use it? Its currently just in 27 servers. Also no exception is thrown

Comment: The bot will need verification once it reaches 100 or more guilds

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński still not working btw, do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the comments on your post you say you have enabled intents, But from your code it doesn't look like you enabled intents in the code. You have to do both. [Link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents) to the docs.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

global client

prefix = "-"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix,intents=intents, case_insensitive=True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.voice_channels:
            for member in channel.members:
                print(member.id)
```

Tested with two users in VC in two different guilds, and both are printed

Comment: I already had the intents set on the top, but dumb me ofc managed to forget to add it as a parameter of the client. Thanks for help!